# How can I reverse the effects of `datetick` on a plot?

Tags: matlab, date, plot

How should I revert the effect of `datetick('x')`?

Shall I reconstruct the ticks and labels manually?

Comment: Please add more explanation of what you mean when you say revert the effect of datetick and what you've already tried to do so.

Comment: Have you used `datetick` before??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [`datetick`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html) converts a set of tick marks and labels for an axis, in this case the `x` axis, it modifies the [`'XTick'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#property_d119e51034), [`'XTickLabel'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#property_d119e51173), and [`'XLim'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#property_d119e50844) properties. This causes the [`'XTickMode'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#property_d119e51115), [`'XTickLabelMode'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#property_d119e51224), and [`'XLimMode'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#property_d119e50962) settings to be set to `'manual'`. Setting these back to `'auto'` will regenerate the default tick marks, labels, and limits for that axis:

```
set(gca, 'XTickMode', 'auto', 'XTickLabelMode', 'auto', 'XLimMode', 'auto');
```

Comment: This is the right choice. I tried this, but my fault, i missed it, or I think so.....